# Как задать кодировку при выгрузке данных из firebird

Tags: кодировка, firebird

здравствуйте.
мне нужно сделать выгрузку таблиц из базы firebird в текстовые файлы, а потом с текстовых файлов - обратно загрузку в базу.
я пользуюсь TIBInputDelimitedFile
STR : TIBInputDelimitedFile;
выгрузка
Str := TIBOUTPUTDELIMITEDFile.Create;
Str.Filename := chosenDirectory+'/T_File1.txt';
Str.ColDelimiter := '  ';
SelectQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT F1, F2,... FROM T_Table1';
SelectQuery.Close;
SelectQuery.BatchOutput(Str);

и соответственно загрузка

Str.Filename := FileListBox.Directory+'\T_File1.txt';
Str.ColDelimiter := '  ';
InsertQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO T_TABLE1(F1, F2,...) VALUES(?F1, ?F2, ...)';
InsertQuery1.BatchInput(Str);

я не нашла как настроить в этом методе кодировку. 
данные выгружаются но назад не загружаются - у меня ощущение что из-за несоответствий кодировки файл неправильно разбирается. при разборе первого же файла он говорит что я пытаюсь 80 символов воткнуть в поле шириной 20.

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.ibase.ru/ibrusfaq/

Comment: 80 вместо 20? Либо текст китайский, либо разбор работает неправильно

Comment: я точно знаю что текст не китайский. файлы спокойно после выгрузки открываются и читаются. а вот с разбором я и прошу помочь . я пользуюсь стандартом. и почему то этот стандарт сам себя не читает. я предполагаю что нужно как то установить кодировку  текста. но не знаю как.

Comment: Ну так проверьте как работает разбор. Проверить что исходный фал соответствует шаблону. Что разбирается на правильные элементы. Есть там возможность тестового разбора без записи в базу?  Исключение на вызове BatchInput не показывает номер итерации или строки файла Str, на которой произошёл сбой? Или просто порядок полей попутали. На место 80-ти попало 20-ти буквенное. И вообще таблицы разные